# How best to regularize high-cardinality fixed effects?

Tags: regularization, fixed-effects-model, high-dimensional, many-categories

Let's say that I have data in the 10s-100s of millions of observations. This data is clustered across hundreds, thousands, or even millions of entities (in a B2B context, these might be corporate customers, or individual store locations). Using specialized packages like R's [Fixest](https://lrberge.github.io/fixest/), it is possible for me to deploy a fixed effects for any of these high-cardinality entities. At the same time, I suspect that introducing the equivalent of tens of thousands (or more) dummy variables means that I'm setting myself up for for pretty serious over-fitting. Can anyone here recommend a statistical method and/or a Python/R package that can facilitate the regularization of high-cardinality fixed effects?

Comment: I'm honestly not 100% sure what you mean in this context by regularization or fixed effects. But yes in general it is not a good idea to dummy code a high-cardinality categorical variable. Does something like target encoding make sense in your situation?

Comment: Hi! Applying fixed effects here would entail fitting an intercept term for every unique value of the category - something which I agree is likely to be problematic at this scale. I'm not familiar with target encoding, but for my use case I'm constrained to some form of regression (OLS/GLM versus classification / CART), since I need to extract the coefficient estimates and standard errors. Is target encoding still viable in this context?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply :). But yes, target encoding still works for GLM models. Like dummy (or one-hot) encoding, it's just a way of representing a categorical predictor as a number. The simplest way to do this is to take the mean of the response for each level of the category, and use that number in a new variable, so you can turn a high-cardinality factor variable into one numeric variable. But there's a lot of ways to do it. The main issue is that some people think this is "cheating" because you look at the response variable twice.

Comment: Thanks again wzbillings - This conversation has been very helpful. I guess sometimes the 'answer' to a question on StackExchange is - "You are asking the wrong qustion." ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am closing out this question with the answer : "If you are attempting to regularize fixed effects with cardinalities in the tens of thousands or higher, then you are not being as parsimonious in your specification as you can be, are at genuine risk of over-fitting, and may be on the wrong track."

wzbillings has already mentioned [target encoding](https://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.TargetEncoder.html) as a solution that obviates the need for regularizing high-cardinality fixed effects. However, an even simpler approach that I intend to take in my own work is to take category-level means of the dependent variable from the pre-analysis period, consolidate that information into a single continuous variable, and ensure that the clustered nature of the data is factored for in the context of the standard error estimation.

Answer (score 1):

I see no problem at all with using regularisation on high cardinality data.
The use case I am thinking of is in **e-commerce**.
In these situations, we typically have a fat-head long tail sales pattern.

I am certainly not suggesting its use for other sorts of data, eg chemical molecules, where I would assume there is no https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle at work

eg Spotify currently has over 11 million artists and creators
but of the  \$8 Billion paid to its artists only 1060 artists earned more than \$1 Million, while 57,000 artists generated $10,000+

in these situations regularisation will cause those top n artists to have a significant coefficient, whilst the majority of artists will have a zero coefficient.
Consider predicting whether a given listener  will 'like' a particular song, and we use artist as a dummy variable.

You can understand this by considering the regularisation parameter in the objective function as "*sum* error per unit of coefficient". so the more listeners (rows) an artist has, the more total error the artist coefficient can reduce; conversely the fewer listeners an artist has, the less impact that artist's coefficient has on the error.

So I would actually recommend having more dummy variables: in the spotify example you might have artists, genres, decade, song ...

the point is that regularisation will push rare occurrences to the average (since there are more plays of a genre than of an individual artist).
so eg most RnB artists' coefficient will be pushed to an average RnB genre coefficient, whilst Drake etc would have a significant coefficient.
Similarly most songs won't have their own coefficient, but you would expect the top 10 of any year to.

[spotify stats](https://www.demandsage.com/spotify-stats/)

Comment: I think that you raise an important point, i.e. is there utility in the coefficient estimate for category X in of itself, or is the fixed effect merely a tool to improve the signal-to-noise ratio for the coefficient estimate of interest? In my case, I have little interest in the individual fixed effects, so having 10s of thousands of dummies would potentially add more problems then they would solve.... but I agree that there are perfectly valid applications for such an approach.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that one possible solution might be to prevent the need for regularization in the first place by dividing the entity of the fixed effects into strata, and then deploying fixed effects based on strata membership. For example, in the context of a fixed effect tied to 100k entities, the number of observations each entity contributes may vary drastically. I can cluster these 100k entities into 1k strata as a function of the relative number of observations each entity contributes, obviating the need for high-cardinality fixed effects entirely while hopefully maintaining the bulk of variance reduction that I would have achieved deploying 100k fixed effects.